# Firestore sorted list - Repeat API call to Firestore X times to iterate over a linked list of Firestore documents

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs

I am experimenting with a "linked list" in Firestore that maintains a sorted list of transactions. I am expecting a high volume of transactions and so I am playing around with the idea of an infinite scroll, where on initial load we pull in the most recent X transactions and then load more in batches of X as needed.

`Transactions` is a collection of documents each representing a transaction. Each document contains a reference to the name of the next document (ie the next most recent transaction).

So for example,

```
Transaction A
  nextDocId: 'Transaction B'
Transaction B
  nextDocId: 'Transaction C'
Transaction C
  nextDocId: 'Transaction D'
```

What is the best way to load X transactions given the starting transaction? If I just pick a value for X (say 10) I could chain 10 `switchMaps/concatMaps` together, but is there a way to do this dynamically? I basically need to repeat an API call X times, but each call requires the response from the last call.

Alternatively, is this solution even viable? I don't see any other way to maintain a sorted list in Firestore so the other option is to sort the entire list of transactions in the client each time.

Comment: Did you already check this guide on [Listen for realtime updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen), and another one is [Transactions and batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got this working using `expand` and `bufferCount`. There were a few tricks, the first was to define the Firestore call in it's own function to get the recursion working as expected,

```
private getNextTransactionRequest(txnId: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.firestore.collection('myCollection').doc(txnId).snapshotChanges().pipe(
        map(response => {
            return response.payload.data();
        })
    );
}
```

Then, to string the calls together,

```
public loadTransactions(headTxnId: string, n: number): Observable<any[]> {
    const getNextTransaction$ = this.getNextTransactionRequest(headTxnId);
    return getNextTransaction$.pipe(
        expand(txn => {
            if (txn) {
                if (txn.nextTransactionId && txn.nextTransactionId != '') {
                    return this.getNextTransactionRequest(txn.nextTransactionId);
                }
            }
        }),
        bufferCount(n),
        take(1)
    );
}
```

`expand` recursively chains the API calls together using the response from the previous call, which is exactly what I needed and `bufferCount` waits until the previous chain of API calls has emitted `n` transactions and emits that at once as an array.

The one catch with `bufferCount` is that if `nTransactions % n != 0` you will lose some transactions. To solve that I think I am just going to keep track of the total number of transactions and the total I have loaded in already. Then if `nTotal - nLoaded < n` I just set `n = nTotal - nLoaded`.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the [expand](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/expand) operator. You can use the operator as described in the excellent article (rxjs core team member) here: [expand explained](https://ncjamieson.com/understanding-expand/)

In the example the next page (in your case transaction) is fetched one-by-one. I try to to find a suggestion.